# How to set value into input that place next from function javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to set value into input that place next from function javascript ?

When tested this code, input `id="yyy"` will get `value = 123` It's ok.

And input `id="xxx"` will blank result and show error. It's ok. i understand.

But if i want to get `value = 123` to input `id="xxx"` with this code (input `id="xxx"` place next from function javascript)

How can i do that ? It's possible ?

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="yy" id="yy"/> 
</form> 
  
<script>
    var test = "123";
 document.getElementById('yy').value = test;
 document.getElementById('xx').value = test;
</script>
  
<br>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="xx" id="xx"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: You're running the JS code *before* the `xx` element exists in the DOM. Either move the <script> tag to the end of the body, or place your JS code in a document.ready event handler

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the `script` before the `element` gets loaded that's y it is giving you `undefined`. Placing it after the element will solve your problem

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="yy" id="yy" />
</form>

<br>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="xx" id="xx" />
</form>
<script>
  var test = "123";
  document.getElementById('yy').value = test;
  document.getElementById('xx').value = test;
</script>
```

Comment: if input id xxx place next from function ? how can i do ?

Comment: write `document.getElementById('xx').value = test;` after the input in different script block